# PHP: Pass a variable in URL via a clicked link

Tags: php, get

I created a function that requires one parameter to be passed into it but I need that parameter to come from another script. How do I embed the variable into a link then put that variable into the function in another script? I know I need to utilize $_GET, isset($_GET['']) and a href but I just can't put it all together.

Comment: do you mean something like `<a href="http://somewhere.com?something=lol">Link</a>` where $_GET['something'] will resolve to "lol" at that targeted page?

Answer (score 5):

$_GET is collection of of query string parameters.  If you had a url like:  test.php?param1=foo&param2=bar  you can access foo by $_GET['param1'] etc..

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_REQUEST['something']`
Your link must be:

```
<a href="test.php?something=something&something1=test">Click Me</a>
```

Inside test.php

```
if(@$_REQUEST['something']=="something"){
    echo $_REQUEST['something1'];
    }
```

When you click `Click Me`, `test.php` would `echo`  "test".